# Prove: A matrix $A \in \mathbb{C}^{m \times n}$ with $m \geq n$ has full rank if and only if it maps no two distinct vectors to the same vector.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank

***Thm***. A matrix $A \in \mathbb{C}^{m \times n}$ with $m \geq n$ has full rank if and only if it maps no two distinct vectors to the same vector.

---

I'm going to write out the proof (given by my text) line by line because there are certain statements I'm not sure about. I'm a little rusty on linear algebra. For each statement of the proof, I'll give a statement from the proof and my analysis immediately below. The converse I will attempt to prove in my own words. Please give constructive feedback on correctness of my interpretation(s).

---

***proof***   ($\implies$)

1. If A is of full rank, its columns are linearly independent, ...

Agreed. Since $m \geq n$ and full rank is defined my the maximum possible dimension spanned by the row or column spaces of $A$, then it must be that the rank of $A$ is $n$ which implies that the $n$ columns of A span $\mathbb{C}^n$. Which is only possible if the $n$ columns are linearly independent.

---

2. ... so they form a basis for range$(A)$.

I think I agree because, since the columns are L.I., they form a basis for $\mathbb{C}^n$, which is the column space of $A$ which is the range of $A$.

---

3. This means every vector $b \in \text{range}(A)$ has a unique linear expansion in terms of the columns of $A$, and therefore has a unique $x$ s.t $b = Ax$.

I have a strong intuition that the expansion is unique, since none of the columns of $A$ can be scaled to each other. But how is this statement proved? Do I consider $x,y$ such that $Ax = b$ and $Ay = b$ and then ($a_i$ are columns of $a$)

$$ y_1a_1 + \cdots + y_na_n = x_1a_1 + \cdots + x_na_n $$ 
$$(y_1 - x_1)a_1 + \cdots + (y_n - x_n)a_n = 0 $$

And since the columns are L.I. the only possible solution set is

$$\{y_1 - x_1 = 0, \dots , y_n - x_n = 0\} \implies x = y$$

---

*Converse* (proof by contraposition).

If $A$ is not of full rank then the columns of $A$ must be be linearly dependent. Therefore there is a nontrivial solution $x$ to the equation

$$Ax = x_1a_1 + \cdots + x_na_n = 0$$

This means that for any other vector $c \in \mathbb{C}^n$ we have

$$Ac = Ax + Ac = A(x+c)$$

so that $x+c$ and $c$ are mapped to the same vector $Ac$. That is, we have shown that *if $A$ is not of full rank, then the mapping is not unique*. So by contraposition, a *unique mapping implies A is of full rank*.

---

Sorry, that wasn't pretty.

Answer (score -1):

Hint: Use [Rank-Nullity Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem)